# What is the best way to set the position for the images in the onDraw method?

Tags: android, image, position, screen-resolution, ondraw

I have a class that extends View so that I can use the onDraw method to draw on the canvas, but the main problem here is that the images are not positioned on the same place when testing with different screen resolutions. What do I need to use in order to see the images on the exact same place?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you want exact same place and size?

Comment: It needs to be at the exact same place, and the size is already ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert pixel to density pixel

```
int xPixels = 100;
int yPixels = 100;

displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

int px = (int) ((xPixels/displayMetrics.density)+0.5);
int py = (int) ((yPixels/displayMetrics.density)+0.5);
```

Use px and py to the position of your image

Comment: Sorry, i edited the formula

Comment: If you find this helpful, check my answer.

Comment: converting from pixel to density pixel does not as efficient as I wanted to see, so I tweaked the width and height to get a better result with the different screen resolutions I have.